# XMLHttpRequest add custom header

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-headers

I would like to pass access_token via HTTP header.

```
_xhr.setRequestHeader('x-customtoken', 'value');
```

When I want to get it on server it's value is null. I get it like this:

```
public final static String HEADER_SECURITY_TOKEN = "x-customtoken";
// ..
request.getHeader(HEADER_SECURITY_TOKEN)
```

Pass the token via header is the only solution for me. I can pass it like a request param, but I need to to it via HTTP-headers.

```
    xhr: function(options){
        var _xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
            _to_send = options.params;

        _xhr.open(options.type, options.url);
        _xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        _xhr.setRequestHeader('x-customtoken', 'value');
        _xhr.responseType = 'json';
        _xhr.onload = function () {
            if (_xhr.status === 200) {
                var _json = _xhr.response;
                if (typeof _json == 'string')
                    _json = JSON.parse(_json);
                options.success(_json);
            } else {
                options.error(_xhr);
            }
        };
        try {
            _xhr.send(_to_send);
        } catch (e){
            options.error(_xhr);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the server-side engine?

Comment: @Nonemoticoner, server side written on java(Spring) and the server is tomcat7

Comment: You know you have to call `setRequestHeader()` after the call to `open()`, and before `send()`

Comment: Did you check that the header was actually included in the request? Most browser developer tools can do that.

Comment: @Nonemoticoner, yes. i check it. and request doesn't contains my header but at the server i get it. so i don't know whats wrong

Comment: @adeneo, yes. i know, i do that

Comment: Paste the whole JS code that concerns sending request so we could reporoduce it.

Comment: @Nonemoticone, look now